# Electric field in a resistor

Tags: voltage, resistors

I have a question, in a circuit is there an electric field across a resistor?, and if yes then how is that electric field generated?.
The reason im asking this is that ive been thinking lately that an electric field should be necessary in order for a voltage drop to occur across a resistor. However reading online i see things like " resistor produces friction which does work on a charge dropping its voltage", this seems wrong to me.

pls correct me if im wrong, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is a field just like in any other conductor. A piece of wire is a resistor too

Comment: Where is a voltage potential difference, there is a electric field.

Comment: At first one could think as this being a simple question. Indeed, for experienced engineers the answer is simple as answered by the collegues above. However the full understanding of the physical effects involving the creation of an electrical field along a resistor (or any other conductor) is more complex and deals with the dynamic propagation of an electric potential through time. Also the electrical current formation will follow the same principles as a consequence from the above. I believe further clarifications are necessary, for which I don't have complete knowledge.

Comment: Yes - without an E-field there would be no force for allowing any movement of electrical charges (which is called "current").

Comment: See Maxwell's equations:  I had a professor once who thought that the correct way to teach EE was to start students out with Maxwell's equations and derive everything else from there.  An interesting idea, but not sure freshman EE students would appreciate it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

There's even a well-known form of Ohm's law,

$$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E},$$

that expresses the effect this field at each location in the resistor. Here,  \$\sigma\$ is the material conductivity, \$\vec{E}\$ is the electric field, and \$\vec{J}\$ is the resulting current density.

You also know that potential difference is defined in terms of the integral of electric field:

$$V_{ba} = -\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{\ell},$$

where \${\rm d}\vec{\ell}\$ is an infinitesimal element of the path from location *a* to location *b*. This tells you there can't be a potential difference between two positions (like the two ends of a resistor) if there is no electric field on the path between them.